# New GAS workplace closes code (tab or window) when you open previous executions. Cannot see both

Tags: google-apps-script

The new Google workplace closes Tools | Script Editor view of code when you click to view completed executions and vice versa. This happens whether the code or log is in a table or in a separate window. How do I see them at the same time?

I am working from the base of a spreadsheet. If I go back to the spreadsheet and open with tools | script editor to see my code the execution log closes!

I opened this question as [New GASworkplace closes code (tab or window) when you open previous executions. Cannot see both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236725/new-gasworkplace-closes-code-tab-or-window-when-you-open-previous-executions)
but someone closed it. I consider this a serious problem.

New information. If you open the script editor and view executions in separate tabs in the old script tool and then switch to the new one the executions is not closed. You can refresh the executions view to see newer runs.

Comment: You should at least delete that question or somebody will close this as a  duplicate of that question. On the other hand, some of us don't have the new editor and your issue is unclear or not reproducible to those who don't have the new features. If this seems to be a bug, create a issue in the issuetracker for Google to deal with this. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I am not able to do either - perhaps someone wit more points can. Please

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. If you have both tabs open, switching one of them is not closing the other one. If what you're asking for instead is that a new tab is open when clicking `Executions`, instead of redirecting from current tab, I'd suggest filing a feature request in Issue Tracker's component: https://issuetracker.google.com/components/985382

Comment: I tried to add could not submit. 
1. Open base Google item. 
2. Click Tools / Script Editor - it opens in a new tab. 
3. Click Executions on the left - S. Editor tab is replaced by Execs. 
4. Go to the base tab and click Tools / S. Editor - Execs tab is replaced by S. Editor. 

In new workplace, you cannot see both your code and your previous execution logging. Workaround: go to the old script editor and View / Executions. You now have three tabs open (base spreadsheet/ form/ whatever), script editor, executions list. Go to the s. editor and switch back to the new editor. Component ?

Comment: @Iamblichus I tried to add to Issue Tracker but could not submit. I am also not sure what to call the component. The text I tried to enter is in my comment above. Please help if you have time. Thanks.

Comment: You can have both script and Executions tab open, you just need to open the project directly from Apps Script dashboard. This is not a bug, but might be worth a feature request. Also, about the problems you are having for reporting this, have you visited the `Templates` tab? `I am also not sure what to call the component` not sure what you mean, you don't need to name the component. `I tried to add to Issue Tracker but could not submit` please provide more details on this.

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus. Using templates I was able to add and did not have to supply a component.  175854520 New App Script Environment: Do not open Executions in place of Script Editor - open in new tab and vice versa